# Codeigniter - select where id not in (another query result)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm working into a hotel booking system, currently I'm trying to select available rooms (not reserved).

```
Rooms DB Structure:
ID
ROOM NAME
CAPACITY

HOTEL RESERVATIONS DB STRUCTURE:
ID
CHECK_IN
CHECK_OUT
ROOMS
...
```

This is my current code:

```
function searchFreeRooms($data){
  $check_in = $data['fields']['check_in'];
  $check_out = $data['fields']['check_out'];
  $this->db->select("*");
  $this->db->from('core_hotel_rooms');
  $this->db->where("id NOT IN (select rooms,total_guests from res_hotel where check_in <= '$check_in' AND check_out >= '$check_in' OR check_in <= '$check_out' AND check_out >= '$check_out' OR check_in >= '$check_in' AND check_out <= '$check_out' ) ");
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
 }
```

A user can book many rooms in one time, and reserved room id's are stored in column "ROOMS" seperated with commas ex: 2, 3, 5

In my front, room that exist in this column should not be displayed but I'm having trouble because only first id(room) before comma is selected, example: 2,3,5 > only 2 is selected and 3,5 still are displayed in my front.

Problem is here: `$this->db->where("id NOT IN (select rooms,total_guests from res_hotel where check_in <= '$check_in' AND check_out >= '$check_in' OR check_in <= '$check_out' AND check_out >= '$check_out' OR check_in >= '$check_in' AND check_out <= '$check_out' ) ");`

I tried this: `$this->db->where("id NOT IN (1, 2) ");` and it works perfectly but not upper method with second query.

Sorry for my english...

Many thanks to all those who can help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally with all your help I've fixed my problem!

Working code:

```
function searchFreeRooms($data){
  $check_in = $data['fields']['check_in'];
  $check_out = $data['fields']['check_out'];
  $query1 = $this->db->query("select rooms from res_hotel where (check_in <= '$check_in' AND check_out >= '$check_in') OR (check_in <= '$check_out' AND check_out >= '$check_out') OR (check_in >= '$check_in' AND check_out <= '$check_out' )");
  $query1_result = $query1->result();
  $room_id= array();
  foreach($query1_result as $row){
     $room_id[] = $row->rooms;
   }
  $room = implode(",",$room_id);
  $ids = explode(",", $room);
  $this->db->select("*");
  $this->db->from('core_hotel_rooms');
  $this->db->where_not_in('id', $ids);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
 }
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Consider using brackets

```
   $this->db->where("id NOT IN (select rooms,total_guests from res_hotel where (check_in <= '$check_in' AND check_out >= '$check_in') OR (check_in <= '$check_out' AND check_out >= '$check_out') OR (check_in >= '$check_in' AND check_out <= '$check_out' ) ) ");
```

Comment: Run second query in phpmyadmin with all values

Comment: Not working!

I did this query in phpmyadmin `select * from core_hotel_rooms where id not in (select rooms from res_hotel where check_in <= '2016-06-24' AND check_out >= '2016-06-24' OR check_in <= '2016-06-30' AND check_out >= '2016-06-30' OR check_in >= '2016-06-24' AND check_out <= '2016-06-30')`

and it shows me those results:

id: 1,2,4,5, this is wrong! id: 4 should be removed from here also because i have this value in rooms column: 3, 4.

When i run second query only results are correct values: 3,4.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem. Hope this help:

```
function searchFreeRooms($data){
  $check_in = $data['fields']['check_in'];
  $check_out = $data['fields']['check_out'];

  $query1 = $this->db->query("select rooms from res_hotel where check_in <= '".$check_in."' AND check_out >= '".$check_in."' OR check_in <= '".$check_out."' AND check_out >= '".$check_out."' OR check_in >= '".$check_in."' AND check_out <= '".$check_out."'")->result_array();
  $room_id= array();
  foreach($query1 as $row){
     $room_id[] = $row->rooms;
   }
  $room = implode(",",$room_id);

  $query = $this->db->query("select * from rooms where id not in (".$room.")");

      return $query->result();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $this->db->select('room')
     ->get('your_table');

    foreach($result as $item) {
        $array[] = $item['id'];         
    }
    $a = implode(',', $array);

$this->where_not_in('id', $a);
```

do something like this.

Comment: The `implode` is actually unnecessary as `where_not_in` can take an array directly.

Comment: I once tried doing it with array but I got the "array to string conversion" error.
could you provide me the code of what you are saying!

Comment: `$this->where_not_in('id', $array)` works just fine as far as I'm aware